# local declaration of variable hides instance variable

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the following error:

```
main.m:14:1: warning: local declaration of 'a' hides instance variable                                                                                              
 -(void)setA:(int)a {self.a=a;}                                                                                                                                     
 ^                                                                                                                                                                  
main.m: In function '-[Arithmetic setB:]':                                                                                                                          
main.m:16:1: warning: local declaration of 'b' hides instance variable                                                                                              
 -(void)setB:(int)b {self.b=b;}
```

And my code is as follows:

```
@interface Arithmetic:NSObject{
    int a,b;
}
-(int)a;
-(void)setA:(int)a;
-(int)b;
-(void)setB:(int)b;
-(int)add;
@end

@implementation Arithmetic
-(int)a{
    return  a;
}

-(void)setA:(int)a {
    self.a=a;
}

-(int)b {
    return b;
}

-(void)setB:(int)b {
    self.b=b;
}

-(int)add {
    return [self a]+[self b];
}

@end
```

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. And it's quite clear. Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: still not getting desired output

Comment: not that this answers you question, but do you know if you just went `@property (nonatomic) int a` all those getters and setters are automatically defined for you, then any getters or settings you need to manually override you can just write them out like you have done so.

Comment: Please don't vote to close this question. It is a perfectly acceptable question. At least explain why you are voting to close.

Comment: @shruthibr You haven't told us what the ‘desired output’ *is*.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite this entire class like this...

```
@interface Arithmetic:NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger a;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger b;

- (NSinteger)add;

@end

@implementation Arithmetic

-(int)add {
    return self.a + self.b;
}

@end
```

The reason you are getting the warning message is because you have an ivar `a` which can be accessed by using `a` (no need for `[self a]`). And then you have a parameter of a method called `a` which hides the ivar.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that warning is because in the function

```
-(void)setA:(int)a {self.a=a;}
```

the parameter `(int)a` is defining a local variable called `a` which hides the `int a` defined in the interface because they both have the same name and the default behaviour is to favour the local variable over the more global one. so its just warning you that if you are trying to access the more global `a`, you wont be.

Comment: how do i access global variable

Comment: @shruthibr I explained that in my answer. The thing you are referring to as "global" is not actually global but you can access it just by using the variable name. `a`